# 2d array falls apart in ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, multidimensional-array

I have a 2D array in JS.

I alert the array before I ajax it and the array is intact and all good.

When I ajax it, I get an error, so I have now ajax'd the array to a page that just runs a var dump and the array tails off half way through and loses structure and data

heres the js

```
  $.ajax({
       type: "POST",            
       url: "ajax/updateElements.php",          
       data: {outerarray:outerarray},                       
       success: function(data){
          alert("data="+data);
        },
            error: function(data){
               alert("error");
    }
     });
```

the php

```
 <?php
   var_dump($_POST['outerarray']);
 ?>
```

and the returned data

```
         data=array(40) {
          [0]=>
          array(20) {
            [0]=>
            string(2) "47"
            [1]=>
            string(2) "46"
            [2]=>
            string(2) "-1"
            [3]=>
            string(3) "100"
            [4]=>
            string(2) "35"
            [5]=>
            string(5) "shape"
            [6]=>
            string(190) "shape"
            [7]=>
            string(1) "0"
            [8]=>
            string(1) "0"
            [9]=>
            string(5) "solid"
            [10]=>
            string(3) "000"
            [11]=>
            string(1) "0"
            [12]=>
            string(0) ""
            [13]=>
            string(1) "1"
            [14]=>
            string(2) "st"
            [15]=>
            string(3) "206"
            [16]=>
            string(2) "54"
            [17]=>
            string(1) "0"
            [18]=>
            string(1) "1"
            [19]=>
            string(1) "F"             
          }...until
          [12]=>
          array(20) {
            [0]=>
            string(2) "33"
            [1]=>
            string(3) "179"
            [2]=>
            string(3) "376"
            [3]=>
            string(3) "578"
            [4]=>
            string(3) "203"
            [5]=>
            string(4) "text"
            [6]=>
            string(933) "text"
            [7]=>
            string(2) "11"
            [8]=>
            string(1) "1"
            [9]=>
            string(5) "solid"
            [10]=>
            string(3) "000"
            [11]=>
            string(1) "0"
            [12]=>
            string(0) ""
            [13]=>
            string(1) "1"
            [14]=>
            string(0) ""
            [15]=>
            string(3) "206"
            [16]=>
            stri
```

and thats where it tails off

any clues? 
I have been banging my head against a wall for a week over this

heres the PDO code

```
      $arraycount=count($_POST['outerarray']);
            for($m=0; $m<$arraycount; $m++){            

                $box_id = $_POST['outerarray'][$m][0];
                $top= $_POST['outerarray'][$m][1];
                $left  = $_POST['outerarray'][$m][2];
                $width = $_POST['outerarray'][$m][3];
                $height = $_POST['outerarray'][$m][4];
                $type = $_POST['outerarray'][$m][5];
                $content = str_replace("\n", "<br>",$_POST['outerarray'][$m][6]);   
                $zindex = $_POST['outerarray'][$m][7];
                $borderwidth = $_POST['outerarray'][$m][8];
                $borderstyle = $_POST['outerarray'][$m][9];
                $bordercolor = $_POST['outerarray'][$m][10];
                $padding = $_POST['outerarray'][$m][11];
                $weblink = $_POST['outerarray'][$m][12];
                $opacity = $_POST['outerarray'][$m][13];
                $shapetype = $_POST['outerarray'][$m][14];
                $page_ref = $_POST['outerarray'][$m][15];
                $site_ref = $_POST['outerarray'][$m][16];
                $deletedelement = $_POST['outerarray'][$m][17];
                $allpages = $_POST['outerarray'][$m][18];
                $pageSection = $_POST['outerarray'][$m][19];    

                $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM site_content WHERE site_ref=:site_ref AND page_ref=:page_ref AND box_id=:box_id");
                $stmt->execute(array(':site_ref' => $site_ref, ':page_ref' => $page_ref, ':box_id' => $box_id));
                $row_count = $stmt->rowCount(); 
                if($row_count==0){  
                $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO site_content(page_ref, site_ref, box_type, box_id, box_top, box_left, box_width, box_height, content, weblink , zindex, border_width, border_colour, border_style, padding, image_opacity, shapetype, allPages, pageSection) VALUES(:field1,:field2,:field3,:field4,:field5,:field6,:field7,:field8,:field9,:field10,:field11,:field12,:field13,:field14,:field15,:field16,:field17,:field18,:field19)");             
                    $stmt->execute(array(':field1' => $page_ref, ':field2' => $site_ref, ':field3' => $type, ':field4' => $box_id, ':field5' => $top, ':field6' => $left, ':field7' => $width, ':field8' => $height, ':field9' => $content, ':field10' => $weblink, ':field11' => $zindex, ':field12' => $borderwidth, ':field13' => $bordercolor, ':field14' => $borderstyle, ':field15' => $padding, ':field16' => $opacity, ':field17' => $shapetype, ':field18' => $allpages, ':field19' => $pageSection));
                    $affected_rows = $stmt->rowCount();                 

                    if($affected_rows !=0){         
                        echo "<br>content added succesfully";
                    }else{
                        echo "<br>no content added";
                    }
                }else{  
                    if($deletedelement=="1"){
                        $stmt = $db->prepare("DELETE FROM site_content WHERE site_ref=:site_ref AND page_ref=:page_ref AND box_id=:box_id");
                        $stmt->execute(array(':site_ref' => $site_ref, ':page_ref' => $page_ref, ':box_id' => $box_id));
                        $stmt->execute();
                        $affected_rows = $stmt->rowCount();

                        if($affected_rows !=0){         
                            echo "<br>content deleted succesfully";
                        }else{
                            echo "<br>no content deleted";
                        }   
                    }else{
                        if($pageSection==''){ $pageSection="C";}     
                        $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE site_content SET box_type=:box_type, box_top=:box_top, box_left=:box_left, box_height=:box_height, box_width=:box_width, content=:content, weblink=:weblink, zindex=:zindex, image_opacity=:image_opacity, border_width=:border_width, border_colour=:border_colour, border_style=:border_style, padding=:padding, shapetype=:shapetype, allPages=:allPages, pageSection=:pageSection WHERE site_ref=:site_ref AND page_ref=:page_ref AND box_id=:box_id");
                        $stmt->execute(array(':box_type' => $type, ':box_top' => $top, ':box_left' => $left, ':box_height' => $height, ':box_width' => $width, ':content' => $content, ':weblink' => $weblink, ':zindex' => $zindex, 'image_opacity' => $opacity, ':border_width' => $borderwidth, ':border_colour' => $bordercolor, 'border_style' => $borderstyle, 'padding' => $padding, 'shapetype' => $shapetype, 'allPages' => $allpages, 'pageSection' =>$pageSection, ':site_ref' => $site_ref, ':page_ref' => $page_ref, ':box_id' => $box_id));
                        $affected_rows = $stmt->rowCount();                        
                        if($affected_rows !=0){         
                            echo "<br>content updated succesfully";
                        }else{
                            echo "<br>no content updated";
                        }
                    }
                }                       

            }
```

Comment: Do you have suhosin installed?

Comment: what is suhosin and why would I need it?

Comment: Could it be the PHP output being cut off instead? Why should it stop at `stri` otherwise?

Comment: @Aioros thats whats confusing me

Comment: Also: what is the error you get?

Comment: my pdo error when I try to insert into db is [12-Dec-2013 12:25:42 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'box_id' cannot be null' in /home/.../updateElements.php:429
Stack trace:
#0 /home/..../updateElements.php(429): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 {main}
  thrown in /home/..../updateElements.php on line 429

Comment: @BarryWatts - I didn't say you need it, I asked whether it's installed. It's a protection system for PHP installations that limits the sizes of arrays among other things. If you have it installed, it might be the piece of the puzzle which cuts off your array or output.

Comment: @N.B. how would I find out if it is installed on a shared server? is there a way without contacting the hosts?

Comment: Just a check: try `var_dump($_POST['outerarray'][30]);`, to see if it's a broken array or a broken output.

Comment: if I var_dump($_POST['outerarray'][30]); I get this output   data=array(20) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "20"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "159"
  [2]=>
  string(2) "42"
  [3]=>
  string(3) "409"
  [4]=>
  string(3) "109"
  [5]=>
  string(4) "text"
  [6]=>
  string(148) "text"
  [7]=>
  string(2) "10"
  [8]=>
  string(1) "0"
  [9]=>
  string(5) "solid"
  [10]=>
  string(3) "000"
  [11]=>
  string(1) "0"
  [12]=>
  string(0) ""
  [13]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [14]=>
  string(0) ""
  [15]=>
  string(3) "211"
  [16]=>
  string(2) "54"
  [17]=>
  string(1) "0"
  [18]=>
  string(1) "0"
  [19]=>
  string(1) "C"
}

Comment: Well, then the array seems to be there. Could you post the code that is giving you the PDO error?

Comment: I will add to the OP as its too long for a comment

Comment: Ok, could it be that one of the `$_POST['outerarray'][$m][0]` is an empty string? That would explain the error. Try to check the value you assign to `$box_id` inside the loop.

Comment: No the box_id has a value in each inner array. I Check this by alerting the array before sending and then echoing it out from the php.

Comment: Could you just echo `$box_id` right before the INSERT statement? For a certain value of `$m`, that must be empty.

Comment: @BarryWatts - you can create a simple PHP script that does this: `var_dump(extension_loaded('suhosin'));` and if it's true - you have it installed.

Comment: @Aioros the box_id that the last to be echoed before failure is '46'

Comment: @N.B. no the returned value is False

Comment: @Aioros the innerarray with the box_id 46 is the last innerarray in the outerarray.  Could this have any bearing on the problem?

Comment: @Aioros I have run the php without the insert and just echoing out the box_id and box_id 46 is attempted to be inserted 8 times but it is interspaced thoughput the array. The loop attempts 48 loops on a 40 element array. This is driving me crackers!!!!

Comment: why is there two $stmt->execute(); in the if($deletedelement=="1"){

Comment: Also, what is the value of $arraycount?

Comment: Could you try `console.log(outerarray)` in JS and check its length and structure in the console?

Comment: arraycount is one too many for the elements in the array. I dont understand why

Comment: @LisaK1308 that was a typo, removed but to no effect

Comment: Wait, so how many elements are in the JS outerarray?

Comment: the array is dynamic to changes in size dependent. but onn the last test the array was 41 elements but arraycount was 42

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43057/discussion-between-aioros-and-barry-watts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so apparently it's a problem with the serialization of the `outerarray` data object in your `$.ajax()` call (maybe an old jQuery version?). To avoid any problem, you could encode your data in a JSON string and decode it in the PHP script, basically like this:

JS:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax/updateElements.php",
    data: {outerarray: JSON.stringify(outerarray)},
    success: function(data) {
        alert("data="+data);
    },
    error: function(data){
        alert("error");
    }
});
```

PHP:

```
$outerarray = json_decode($_POST['outerarray']);
...
$arraycount = count($outerarray);
for ($m=0; $m<$arraycount; $m++) {            
    $box_id = $outerarray[$m][0];
    $top = $outerarray[$m][1];
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Check post_max_size in your php.ini settings and check it against the size of the POST

Comment: my post_max_size is 500M how do I find the size of the POST?

Comment: It is unlikely your are breaking the post_max_size so what about the max_input_vars setting?

Comment: max_input_vars is 1000